# sql - getting sum of same column from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum

I have a few tables in my DB. Let's call them table1, table2, table3.
All of them have a column named `value`.
I need to create a query that will return a single number, where this number is the sum of all the `value` columns from all the tables together...
I've tried the following way:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(value) FROM table1) + (SELECT SUM(value) FROM table2) + (SELECT SUM(value) FROM table3) as total_sum
```

But when at least one of the inner `SUM` is `NULL`, the entire total value (`total_sum` here) is `NULL`, so that's not very trustworthy.
When there is no value in a certain inner `SUM` query, I need it to return 0, so it doesn't affect the rest of the `SUM`.

To make it more clear, let's say I have the following 2 tables:

TABLE1:

```
  ID  |  NAME  |  VALUE
   1    Name1     1000
   2    Name2     2000
   3    Name3     3000
```

TABLE2:

```
  ID  |  NAME  |  VALUE
   1    Name1     1500
   2    Name2     2500
   3    Name3     3500
```

Eventually, the query I need will return a single value - 13500, which is the total sum of all the values under the `VALUE` column of all the tables here.

All the other columns have no meaning for the needed query, and I even don't care much for performance in this case.

Comment: I would probably just use `union all` to stick all those values together, then do the sum over all at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it using [Coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as follows

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT coalesce(SUM(value),0) FROM table1) + 
    (SELECT coalesce(SUM(value),0) FROM table2) + 
    (SELECT coalesce(SUM(value),0) FROM table3) as total_sum
```

Another approach is to use `union all` to merge all values into single table

```
select distinct coalesce(sum(a.value), 0) as total_sum from
    (select value from table1
      union all
    select value from table 2
      union all
    select value from table 3) a;
```

Comment: The selected answer here relates to the first part of this answer only, as this solution returns only 1 record with 1 field, holding the total sum, as needed. The solution with the union returns a recordset of several records (one for each selected table and that's not what I need here). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ISNULL function to take care of the NULLs.

```
SELECT ISNULL((
                  SELECT SUM(value) FROM table1
              )
            , 0
             ) + ISNULL((
                            SELECT SUM(value) FROM table2
                        )
                      , 0
                       ) + ISNULL((
                                      SELECT SUM(value) FROM table3
                                  )
                                , 0
                                 ) AS total_sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply sum all of them:

```
select sum(total) as Total
from (
select sum(value) as total from Table1
union all
select sum(value) as total from Table2
union all
select sum(value) as total from Table3 
) t;
```

Comment: If I use union all, I get a recordset of several records (one per selected table), and I want a recordset of 1 record only...

Comment: @TheCuBeMan, and the code I gave returns just one record. You could try.